# c:forEach throws javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'foo' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl, el, propertynotfoundexception

My project is using hibernate 3.4.0 GA  to access database, and Spring MVC 2.5.6 to handle web request and jsp(jstl) to render view(web page).

I get an entity list from database, by hibernate, and add it as model into modelmap for jsp.When jsp rendering my webpage, it throws a "javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException".

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'timestamp' not found on type java.lang.String

and the exception comes from:

```
<c:forEach var="statusHistory" items="statusHistoryList">
    ${statusHistory.timestamp}
</c:forEach>
```

It seems like that "statusHistory" is considered as a String, but not an object.

The "StatusHistory" class has "timestamp" property and the getter method:

```
public Class StatusHistory{
    ...
    private Date timestamp;
    public Date getTimestamp(){...}
    ...
}
```

I have searched on google for one whole day. Some post says that the getter method is not following the convention. But it seems it's not my case.
can some one please help me?

Thanks in advance
Andrew

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here,

```xml
<c:forEach var="statusHistory" items="statusHistoryList">
```

You're supplying the `items` attribute of `<c:forEach>` with a plain vanilla String with a value of `"statusHistoryList"` which in turn indeed doesn't have a `getTimestamp()` method.

You need to reference it using an EL expression `${...}` instead.

```
<c:forEach var="statusHistory" items="${statusHistoryList}">
    ${statusHistory.timestamp}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: statusHistoryList is List<StatusHistory>, and I iterator it with jstl/core:forEach method. do you mean it's a  wrong way to access data in jsp?

Comment: Did you compare the code snippet in my answer with yours? Note how the `items` attribute is now been set. To learn more about EL, check our wiki page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Comment: O, I made a typing mistake in my post. it's "${statusHistoryList}" in my .jsp code.

Comment: Then you're either not running the code you think you're running (save, rebuild, redeploy, restart, etc), or your controller has actually put a `String`, not a `List<StatusHistory>` in the scope. E.g. by `request.setAttribute("statusHistoryList", "statusHistoryList")` instead of `request.setAttribute("statusHistoryList", statusHistoryList)`.

Comment: k. you are right. I make a stupid typing mistake in my controller. thank you so umch

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had not added `implements java.io.Serializable` to the bean so it was not identifying bean's property

> Following are the unique characteristics that distinguish a JavaBean
>   from other Java classes −
>
> ```
> It provides a default, no-argument constructor.
>
> It should be serializable and that which can implement the Serializable interface.
>
> It may have a number of properties which can be read or written.
>
> It may have a number of "getter" and "setter" methods for the properties.
> ```

[Reference tutorialspoint-JSP](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_java_beans.htm)

Once added it fixed the issue.

Comment: Deleted other answer from another question

Answer (score -1):

Keep it like

```
<c:forEach var="statusHistory" items="${statusHistoryList}">
           ${statusHistory.timestamp}
</c:forEach>
```

Make sure to check items in forEach loop sometimes it acts like a string due to an extra space. Try retyping it.